# How to completely uninstall Visual Studio on M1 Mac?

Tags: configuration, frameworks, uninstallation

How to uninstall for complete Visual Studio preview version (2022) for m1 Mac?

I try deleting the folders and the application, the jsons, and configurations, but it still exist on my computer, so I don´t know how to clear all the things in or with some type of relation with the app.